# When and why GLPK_MI switches to dual simplex

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy, glpk

I use CVXPY with GLPK_MI solver to solve a mixed-integer programming problem. The solver starts with simple simplex, but after some tries, it switches to use "long-step dual simplex" (see the below log file from the solver.) I am wondering when and why GLPK_MI decides to switch its approach? Is there any parameter to change/set this switching point? Is there any way to stop the solver (i.e., with or without optimum solution) after trying simple simplex and before using dual simplex?

Thanks in advance for your time and help!

```
[21:05:53] [INFO] [dku.utils]  - -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[21:05:53] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -                                 Numerical solver                               
[21:05:53] [INFO] [dku.utils]  - -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[21:05:53] [INFO] [dku.utils]  - (CVXPY) Aug 19 09:05:53 PM: Invoking solver GLPK_MI  to obtain a solution.
[21:05:53] [INFO] [dku.utils]  - (CVXPY) Aug 19 09:05:53 PM: Applying reduction ConeMatrixStuffing
[21:05:53] [INFO] [dku.utils]  -       0: obj =   0.000000000e+00 inf =   1.822e+03 (1230)
[21:05:53] [INFO] [dku.utils]  - *  4138: obj =  -2.197596897e+07 inf =   1.422e-13 (0) 3
[21:05:53] [INFO] [dku.utils]  - Long-step dual simplex will be used
[21:05:53] [INFO] [dku.utils]  - +  4138: mip =     not found yet >=              -inf        (1; 0)
[21:05:53] [INFO] [dku.utils]  - +  4153: >>>>>  -2.197593056e+07 >=  -2.197593092e+07 < 0.1% (16; 0)
[21:05:53] [INFO] [dku.utils]  - +  4153: mip =  -2.197593056e+07 >=     tree is empty   0.0% (0; 31)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some guessing:

#### Why / when dual simplex?

Dual-Simplex is *the* default-choice in **B**ranch-**a**nd-**C**ut based search. You really want to use it when solving Integer Programming problems!

Why? Basically because adding cuts or enforcing branching-decisions, things you do in BnC during search usually destroys primal feasibility (you got a primal feasible solution and added a new cut / constraint: it might be infeasible now) and additional work would be needed (to repair feasibility).

In Dual-Simplex, those cuts do not destroy dual-feasibility. You might have lost dual-optimality but can easily continue to optimize here.

#### Your example - Switching Simplex-Method

Your logs indicate, that the solver changes to dual-simplex exactly in the moment, when branch-and-cut is starting.

Before this, there was no *mip* indicator and i guess it's about *solving the root-node* / aka *root-relaxation*. You could have done that with primal- or dual-simplex. Solver might decide this in terms of problem-statistics (e.g. variables vs. constraint ratio).

But then, BnC starts and the solver will exploit the nice characteristics of the dual-simplex i outlined above.

#### Remarks

Your other question do no make much sense to me in general. It's not guaranteed, that you obtained *any feasible solution* when the *switch* is happening and i'm not sure what you would do with the root-node solution then.

I mean: you can just drop MIP-based optimization and just solve the LP-relaxation. This is equivalent to `Is there any way to stop the solver (i.e., with or without optimum solution) after trying simple simplex and before using dual simplex?` in some way... But again... That's not something which makes much sense.

In regards to parameterization, *i bet, you can explicitly set the algorithm for those two phases (root-node, BnC search)*. Consider reading GLPKs documentation which is very complete! (But keep in mind: those solvers are often very good / better as the user in regards to deciding those things for you)

Comment: Thanks for your complete response. My question may not make sense for an optimization problem because I do not like to solve the problem in this step. My problem has a high risk of infeasibility, and GLPK may return an infeasible solution after 5-6 hours of running. My aim in this step is to do a pre-screening before running the actual optimization and identity if the optimization has a low chance of finding a feasible solution (even with potential false-positive alerts). So, I can do some constraint adjustments beforehand. Do you know if there is any library/software to do the pre-screening?

Comment: Deciding feasibility is as hard as optimizing in theory. In practice, people probably model their problems *soft*. E.g. instead of `x0 + x2 <= 2`, you got `x0 + x2 <= 2 + penalty_component_0` and minimize `sum(penalty_component_i)`. This has the advantage, that optimization is then some kind of *any-time* process. You will obtain a solution quickly and progress means minimizing the amount of *corrections* needed. Apart from that, you might just use time-outs and *correct* your problem each 15 minutes as long as you don't have a solution. But i would prefer a form of the former.